# WebClient same request works on WinForms but doesn't work on WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, webclient

Here is my code:

```
    var client = new WebClient();
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " +    "SECRETCODE";
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Host] = "api.quizlet.com";
    client.UploadStringCompleted += ClientOnUploadStringCompleted;

    client.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("https://api.quizlet.com/oauth/token"), "POST", string.Format("grant_type={0}&code={1}&redirect_uri={2}",
        HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("authorization_code"), HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(code), HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(AfterOAuthUrl)));
```

When I test this code in WinForms, I recieve proper token, but when I use this on WP7, it throws exception: Remote server returned: "Not found". What should I do? Is this the WP certificate problem, or do I have to do something different on WP7?

Comment: If you remove setting the host property on WinForms, does it still work or does it return the same error as WP does?

Comment: Removed Host header and it still works on WinForms, what does it mean?

Comment: Nothing yet. Can you add the following to the WinForms code and tell me if it keeps on working? Referer: `Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Referer] = "file:///Applications/Install/9036AAF3-F213-4CFB-B57E-576A05E1896D/Install/";`

Comment: It throws an exception: " Remote server returned an error: Wrong request" (Translated to english, so...). It throws this error both with or without host property.

Answer (score 1):

Okay... Try the following:

```
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Referer] = "http://api.quizlet.com";
```

If that doesn't work:

```
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Referer] = "api.quizlet.com";
```

In the WP project. Let me know if it doesn't work.